# My output is not correct when displayed

Tags: c++, class, output

My output name is not being displayed in my program.  I have been looking at the code and
I just can't find my error

input

```
name : John Dough
id : 123445
start date : 10312014
shift: 2
```

output

```
name : ^^^^^^    <<<< I am having problem my name not being displayed
id : 123445
start date : 10312014
shift : 2
```

code

```
//This program demostrates a class and a derived class with constructors.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Employee
{
private:
    char EmpName;
    int EmpNum;
    int HireDate;
public:
    void setEmpName(char);
    void setEmpNum(int);
    void setHireDate(int);
    char getEmpName() const;
    int getEmpNum() const;
    int getHireDate() const;
    Employee();
};
void Employee::setEmpName(char x)
{
    EmpName = x;
}
void Employee::setEmpNum(int y)
{
    EmpNum = y;
}
void Employee::setHireDate(int z)
{
    HireDate = z;
}
char Employee::getEmpName() const
{
    return EmpName;
}
int Employee::getEmpNum() const
{
    return EmpNum;
}
int Employee::getHireDate() const
{
    return HireDate;
}
Employee::Employee()
{
    cout << "I will ask you some questions about an employee.\n\n";
}
class ProductionWorker : public Employee
{
    private:
        int Shift;
        double HourlyPayRate;
    public:
        void setShift(int);
        void setHourlyPayRate(double);
        int getShift() const;
        double getHourlyPayRate() const;
        ProductionWorker();
};
void ProductionWorker::setShift(int a)
{
    Shift = a;
}
void ProductionWorker::setHourlyPayRate(double b)
{
    HourlyPayRate = b;
} 
int ProductionWorker::getShift() const
{
    return Shift;
}
double ProductionWorker::getHourlyPayRate() const
{
    return HourlyPayRate;
}
ProductionWorker::ProductionWorker()
{
    cout << "After answering the questions,\n";
    cout << "I will display the employee's information.\n\n\n";
}
int main()
{
    ProductionWorker info;
    char name[100];
    int num;
    int date;
    int shift;
    double rate;
    cout << "What is the employee's name? ";
    cin.getline(name, 100);

    cout << "What is the employee's number? ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "What is the employee's hire date?\n";
    cout << "(Month, day, and year without any slashes,\n";
    cout << "dashes, commas, or other punctuation.)\n";
    cout << "For example, January 14, 1983 would look like 01141983. ";
    cin >> date;

    cout << "Does the employee work shift 1 or shift 2? ";
    cin >> shift;

    cout << "How much does the employee make per hour? ";
    cin >> rate;
    info.setEmpName(name[100]);
    info.setEmpNum(num);
    info.setHireDate(date);
    info.setShift(shift);
    info.setHourlyPayRate(rate);
    cout << "\n\nHere is the employee's data:\n\n";
    cout << "Employee's Name: " << info.getEmpName() << endl;
    cout << "Employee's Number: " << info.getEmpNum() << endl;
    cout << "Employee's Hire Date: " << info.getHireDate() << endl;
    cout << "Employee's Shift: " << info.getShift() << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << "Employee's Hourly Pay Rate: $" << info.getHourlyPayRate() << endl << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The "info.setEmpName(name[100]);" line should be "info.setEmpName(name);"

Comment: Note that I/O (`cout << ...`) in the constructor should be avoided. It doesn't separate concerns: the user interface (I/O) from storing the data (the class). Move those instructions into main.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong: **you're accessing an out-of-range character** instead of passing the array to the function

```
char name[100];
//.. initialize name..
info.setEmpName(name[100]); // Accesses the 100th character (out-of-range [0-99])

void Employee::setEmpName(char x)
{
    EmpName = x;
}
```

I would go for using `std::string` by changing EmpName (also wrong, it's **not** a single character) to a `std::string`

```
class Employee
{
private:
    string EmpName;
    int EmpNum;
    int HireDate;
public:
    void setEmpName(std::string& name);
    void setEmpNum(int);
    void setHireDate(int);
    string getEmpName() const;
    int getEmpNum() const;
    int getHireDate() const;
    Employee();
};
```

Also don't forget to change `char name[100]` to a `std::string` in the main function.

<kbd>[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/SE6OXi)</kbd>

You can of course accomplish this also with char arrays, in that case if you intend to use a fixed-size array you could either pass it by reference or just copy the content of a pointer to the array into a memory array for `Employee`.

Comment: That was real silly of my going the extra step of creating a char array when i could have just used a string.  Thank you I was looking and could not find that problem 100 thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First, the data type of Employee::EmpName should not be char. It should be a char array or even better would be a std::string.

Second the parameter of the setEmpName function should be either a const char* or a const std::string&.

Third, the name variable should perhaps be a std::string instead of a char array. Of course if you make that change the parameter of the setEmpName function should be const std::string&.

Fourth, when calling the setEmpName function you should just call it as follows: info.setEmpName(name).

Next, you should use std::getline(cin, name) instead of cin.getline(name, 100).

Answer (score 0):

I'm first correcting your mistakes and then giving you a better alternative solution.

The member of your class and the setter function's parameter are only *a single char*. Change them to arrays:

```
char EmpName[100];
```

and

```
void setEmpName(char[]);
```

and in the implementation, you need to copy the content of the given array to your member:

```
void Employee::setEmpName(char[] x) {
    memcpy(EmpName, x, 100);
}
```

However, this is **the C way to do this**.

**The C++ way to do this** is to use `std::string`. For this, change the types of the member, the parameters in the setter and in the getter as well as the type in `main` to `std::string`. To read a `std::string`, use the free-standing overload of `getline` which only takes the stream and the string (but no count):

```
getline(cin, name);
```